# Accessing a built-in class with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, built-in

I would like to retrieve built-in class from Python using a string. By trial/error, I have found a way to achieve it:

```
>>> __builtins__.__dict__['str']
<class 'str'>
>>> __builtins__.__dict__['int']
<class 'int'>
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do it? Is there a safer way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to do it through [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) and not grab a modules `__dict__`. Grabbing dunders is generally not the best idea since they are subject to change; that's why built-in functions like `vars` are around; it goes and grabs the dictionary for the object you provide,

So, instead of:

```
>>> __builtins__.__dict__['str']
```

use:

```
>>> vars(__builtins__)['str']
```

with the same effect while also being safe and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Python's built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function which would avoid referencing anything with a double-underscore name (and be safe since the string is from a trusted source):

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
current directory: "C:\vols\Files\PythonLib\Stack Overflow"
>>> eval('str')
<class 'str'>
>>> eval('int')
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Is using eval a safe behaviour in programming?

Comment: It depends on the source of the string being evaluated. Regardless, you mitigate what can be done by supplying it with a custom globals dictionary that will to restrict what, if any, built-ins can be used by the expression evaluated.